# Even though ubuntu is seeing my serial port, It wont send or recive data

Tags: modem, serial-port

I have been having trouble with my serial port on my ubuntu server 16.04 machine. First off its a lenovo thinkcentre M-57 model 6071, and here is the output of uname -a:

```
Linux server 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:28:22 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

So here is the deal, this machine has a serial port on the motherboard, and I am trying to use it with my modem. The serial port is recognized by the system as ttyS4, and I can even enter a screen session on that port, but when I start typing no data is sent to my modem (My modem has an analog loopback feature so that it will return everything typed back to the terminal, and this has worked on other computers) and no data is received either, it acts as though I am not sending data to the right port, but this is the only physical port detected. The serial port is providing some current, because when I connect my modem to it, the DTR light comes on. So here is some more information:

```
    nikolai@server:~$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    0.987516] 0000:00:03.3: ttyS4 at I/O 0x1c90 (irq = 17, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A

nikolai@server:~$ sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123456]
[sudo] password for nikolai: 
/dev/ttyS0, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS4, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x1c90, IRQ: 17
/dev/ttyS5, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS6, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0

nikolai@server:~$ stty -F /dev/ttyS4 -a
speed 9600 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

I'm pretty stumped on this one, I hope one of you out there can help me out. I went ahead and ordered a pci serial port card, but that's coming from China so it'll take a month. Meanwhile I'd like to get to the bottom of this, I'm hoping it's not a driver issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add your user to the dialout group?

Comment: Jean-Marie, yes I did. same problem.  By the way thanks for replying!!

Comment: Now I have been running screen as sudo, so does the dial out group still matter in this case?

Comment: Does it work with sudo? I do not think the dialout group is needed for sudo (root)

Comment: It does not, this is why I'm stumped

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: Incorrectly modifying settings in your computer's BIOS configuration may lead to a damaged or otherwise inoperable system. Do this at your own risk, and take precaution**.

Try disabling any accompanying parallel ports in the BIOS if applicable as I have personally seen this start a serial port working in a Debian based machine. If possible, change the flow control option from hardware to Xon/Xoff as other options may be preventing the modem from replying to the host.